# Cant display 0 value if data is not exists

Tags: sql

I want to display all data but on certain day there is no output its
 still display data but its wrong. Data on monday and tuesday on second photo is wrong. Value must be 0

```
select sum(Qtyinspect3k) as '3k', sum(Qtyinspect10k) as '10k', 
sum(QtyDefect) as 'reject' 
from dbo_OQAVMView 
whereYear like '2019' and WorkWeek between 'ww01' AND 'ww02' 
and Day = 'Saturday' and not exists ( select * from dbo_OQAVMView 
where LotNo is not null and Year is not null  )
```

[image: Correct Output]

[image: Wrong and current Output]

Comment: Create a help table (or cte) with all wanted dates. Outer join.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the 'Correct' and 'Wrong' output. Furthermore, your query has little to do with the output shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement to get the correct output. I cannot give you a complete query as I cannot understand your code well, however this syntax should help:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(column) != NULL THEN SUM(column) 
        ELSE 0 
    END
FROM table
```

Hope this helps :)